# Games display across both monitors when opened

Tags: multiple-monitors, games, xrandr, fullscreen

I am not sure what setting to change for this but I open games like Dungeon Crawl or a Steam game and the game wants to take up both screens.  Is there a way to have the game open just on one screen `xrandr` shows this.  So they are both on Screen 0:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2966 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192

LVDS1 connected 1366x768+1600+75 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm

VGA1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
```

If you need any more info or can point me to a place you may have already found an answer please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have two monitors connected to my Xubuntu 14.04 machine right now and encountered the same problem. I think that the best way to fix this is through a script file, so that you don't have to enter the commands every time you want to play the game.

I have written a script file that, among other things, will fix the Dungeon Crawl Tiles window to consume only one desktop, instead of spanning across two. You may download or view it [here](http://techlorebyigor.blogspot.com/search/label/dungeon%20crawl%20cheat).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any clean solution to this right now. The easiest workaround is to use `xrandr` and set it to only use one monitor before starting the game with:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

And when you are done with the game reenable both monitors with:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 \
         --mode "1366x768" \
         --panning 1366x768+1600+75 \
       --output VGA1 \
         --mode "1600x900" \
         --panning "1600x900+0+0"
```

Another alternative is to start the game in a window-mode and then remove the screen border with some hackery. I have written a tool for that, available at:

- https://github.com/Grumbel/fullscreen-tools

But it's not really end-user ready or anything. You use it like this (move you mouse pointer over the game window before the 2 seconds ran out):

```
sleep 2 && ./windowtool.py -keep-above 1 --decorations 0 -m 1366,0 ACTIVE
```

If the game doesn't provide a resolution that fits your desktop, you can use `xrandr` to set your monitor to a resolution that fits the game.